# Sentence reverse in java

Tags: java, string, loops

So i'm trying to reverse a sentence and even though I don't have any errors when compiling, it tells me my reverse sentence is out of bounds.

-It should work like this: "hello, world!" --> !dlrow ,olleh"

Said code:

```
    String sentence="this is a sentence!";
    String reverseSentence=sentence;
    for(int counter=0;counter<sentence.length();counter++)
    {
        char charToReplace,replaceChar;

        charToReplace = reverseSentence.charAt(counter);
        replaceChar = sentence.charAt(sentence.length()-counter);

        reverseSentence=reverseSentence.replace(charToReplace, replaceChar);

        System.out.println(reverseSentence);
    }
```

Comment: `replace` does not do what you think it does here. Read its Javadoc.

Comment: And why replace at all? Why dont you use a StringBuilder and append the characters of the input string in reverse order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the exception you are getting is that in `sentence.charAt(sentence.length()-counter)`, `sentence.length()-counter` is out of bounds when counter is 0. Should be `sentence.length()-1-counter`.

However, as Tunaki commented, there are other problems with your code. I suggest you use a `StringBuilder` to construct the reversed `String`, instead of using `replace` (which would replace any occurrence of the first character with the second character).

Comment: Thank you Eran! Tried it and did it as it should've!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't show you an error because the Exception concerning the indexes happen at RunTime.

Here :

```
replaceChar = sentence.charAt(sentence.length()-counter);
```

You're trying to access index 19 of your String (19-0). Replace it with :

```
replaceChar = sentence.charAt(sentence.length()-counter-1);
```

---

I'd recommend to use a `StringBuilder` in your situation though.

Either use the `reverse()` method :

```
String sentence = "this is a sentence!";
String reversed = new StringBuilder(sentence).reverse().toString();
System.out.println(reversed); // Prints : !ecnetnes a si siht
```

Or use the `append()` method for building your new String object. This uses less memory than using a `String` because it is not creating a new `String` object each time you're looping :

```
String sentence = "this is a sentence!";
StringBuilder reversed = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0 ; i < sentence.length() ; i++){
    reversed.append(sentence.charAt(sentence.length() - 1 - i));
}

System.out.println(reversed.toString()); // Prints : !ecnetnes a si siht
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use character arrays to implement your requirement like this,

```
    String sentence = "ABDEF";
    char[] firstString = sentence.toCharArray();
    char[] reversedString = new char[sentence.length()];

    for (int counter = 0; counter < sentence.length(); counter++) {
        reversedString[counter] = firstString[sentence.length() - counter -1];
    }
    System.out.println(String.copyValueOf(reversedString));
```

Answer (score 0):

It maybe better to do it without any replacement, or for loop.  It you create a char array from the string, reverse the array, then create a string from the reversed array this would do what you've asked without any moving parts or replacements.  For example:

```
    String hw = "hello world";
    char[] hwChars = hw.toCharArray();
    ArrayUtils.reverse(hwChars);
    String wh = new String(hwChars);
    System.out.println(wh);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just split the String at each whitespace and put it in String array and then print the array in reverse order

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String sentence = "this is a sentence!";
    String[] reverseSentence = sentence.split(" ");

      for (int i = reverseSentence.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        System.out.print(" " + reverseSentence[i]);
      }

    }
```

Comment: This prints the words in the sentence in reverse order, but the characters in the words are still in the correct order.  The OP has the characters in the words reversed too.